# Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_new_user() in

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

Have a wordpress theme with custom registration.  Registration works on the registration page.  If I take the form and place it on another page , eg. Homepage.  When I try to register it spits back

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_new_user() in C:\wamp\www\mysite\wp-content\themes\mysitetheme\functions\theme-access.php on line 74
```

If I put the reg form in an iframe on the homepage it works and registers the user correctly.  It seems it has something to do with the theme-access.php wanting the url wp-login.php?action=register.

For the life of me I cannot understand why it only registers on the register page an not outside.

Here is the code with my [form](http://pastebin.com/sqyW4yYE), and the functions [code](http://pastebin.com/KtaqaP89).

Why won't  register_new_user() work if the form is placed anywhere else?

Comment: Isn't `register_new_user` deprecated? I think you should be using `wp_create_user()` instead: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

Comment: It is depreciated but still register_new_user still works with the latest wp version.  The error i'm getting has nothing to do with that.